# What’s the formula for finding the sides of a rectangle given Area and Perimeter

Tags: geometry, rectangles

I have been trying to figure this out for some time now and I managed to find some videos on google of them solving the problem with certain values, but I need to write down a concise formula with variables, thanks in advance to anyone who can help me:D

Comment: It's just a symmetric system. Have you looked up for anything in your book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m$ and $n$ be the sides of a rectangle with area $A$ and perimeter $P$. Then
$$A=mn\\
\dfrac P2=m+n$$
Then the quadratic equation having $m$ and $n$ as its roots is
$$x^2-\dfrac P2x+A=0$$
Apply quadratic formula.